# How to sum 2 log files in pig

Tags: hadoop, sum, apache-pig

I have problem, sum 2 log files.

example files:

1. file-1

   id user view

   1  AAA  2

   2  BBB  5

   3  CCC  9
2. file-2

   id user view address

   1  AAA  5    XXX

   2  BBB  2    YYY

   6  FFF  4    ZZZ

i want sum two file by id and sum (view), i hope output:

output:

```
id user view address
1  AAA  7    XXX
2  BBB  7    YYY
```

i should try code join two files, but i don't sum two files:

My code:

```
inputdata = LOAD '/user/hdfs/tes/part-1' AS (
    id:chararray, 
    user:chararray, 
    view:int
);


inputdata2 = LOAD '/user/hdfs/tes/part-2' AS (
    id:chararray, 
    user:chararray, 
    view:int,
    address:chararray
);


joined = JOIN inputdata BY id LEFT OUTER, inputdata2 by id;

outputlist = FOREACH joined {

        GENERATE
        inputdata::id, 
        inputdata::user, 
        --sum(inputdata2::view), 
        inputdata2::address;


}

dump outputlist;
```

iam question, how to sum view in two log files.??

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Get the join result n a foreach loop and sum up the view values.This will work.

```
A = LOAD 'file1.dat' using PigStorage(' ') AS (a:chararray,b:chararray,c:int);                  
B = LOAD 'file2.dat' using PigStorage(' ') AS (a:chararray,b:chararray,c:int,d:chararray);      
C = JOIN A by a,B by a;                                                                                                                           
D = FOREACH C GENERATE A::a as id,A::b as user,A::c + B::c as view,B::d as address;
```

Output:

```
(1,AAA,7,XXX)
(2,BBB,7,YYY)
```

Comment: I am glad it worked. Accept the answer if it resolves your issue.